# Python - Converting HTML hyperlinks to formatted plain text

Tags: python, html, string, format, pypi

How do I convert HTML hyperlinks into plain text with Python that looks like this:

```html
<p>Hello world, it's <a href="https://google.com">foo bar time</a></p>
```

My current code looks like this but this package doesn't seem to do the job themselves as they just convert primary HTML text elements to plain text without the link:

```py
from html2text import html2text

text = html2text("<p>Hello world, it's <a href="https://google.com">foo bar time</a></p>")
print(text)

# Result I wanted: "Hello world, it's foo bar time - https://google.com/"
# Result I got: "Hello world, it's foo bar time"
```

Would really help out if a solution is found.

Comment: Aizak, this looks like a fun little Python puzzle: Have you considered implementing the solution yourself? There are a number of possible approaches using only Python built-ins and stdlib.

For example, you could iterate over all the characters in the HTML string, and when you hit the token "<" start storing its relevant contents into a separate variable called `url` or something.

For a different approach, you could use the `re` package to capture from and transform the input string in a similar fashion to the above.

Comment: I did try a bunch of regular expressions with multiple types of elements in it, but I had 0 clue on how to just center out the two things: the text and the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), this lib should definitely suffice your needs.

Example from the documentation:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from html.entities import name2codepoint

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Start tag:", tag)
        for attr in attrs:
            print("     attr:", attr)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("End tag  :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Data     :", data)

    def handle_comment(self, data):
        print("Comment  :", data)

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        c = chr(name2codepoint[name])
        print("Named ent:", c)

    def handle_charref(self, name):
        if name.startswith('x'):
            c = chr(int(name[1:], 16))
        else:
            c = chr(int(name))
        print("Num ent  :", c)

    def handle_decl(self, data):
        print("Decl     :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Beautiful Soup ([bs4 package](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/))

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

spam = """<p>Hello world, it's <a href="https://google.com">foo bar time</a></p>
<p>Hello world, it's <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">spam eggs</a></p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(spam, 'html.parser')

for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    a_tag.replace_with(f"{a_tag.text} - {a_tag.get('href')}")

print(soup.text)
```

Output

```
Hello world, it's foo bar time - https://google.com
Hello world, it's spam eggs - https://stackoverflow.com
```

Note, you can work from here. Look at `tag.replace_with()` and `tag.unwrap()`
[Link to the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup module.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<p>Hello world, it's <a href='https://google.com'>foo bar time</a></p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

text = soup.get_text()
url_part = soup.find('a')
url_str = url_part['href']

print(text , ' - ' , url_str)
```

To import the module, you need to install it

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```